# "Do my best" vs. "my level best"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, speech

Is there any difference between these two sentences? Which one is grammatical in speech?

> - I will do my best.
> - I will do my level best.

Comment: Have you looked up [*level*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/level?s=t) in a dictionary? See definition 36.

Comment: They are both correct/grammatical. The second one adds more color.

Comment: OP doesn't ask about the etymology of *"**level** best"* - which might be a bit more complex. I think it's General Reference that it means *"**very** best"*, so all we're really dealing with here is the difference between *trivial* and *very trivial*.

Comment: A lesser stackexchange might have provided a single link to a standard internet reference source. For anyone else who stumbled upon this like myself, The Free Dictionary has a good definition drawn from the _McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs_: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/level+best

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go for "I will do my best." "level best" is cliched and unnecessary to express this idea.

Comment: thanks for rpl ,but once i said "I will do my best" my senior (having good communication skills) corrected me, "I will do my level best."

Comment: I half-guessed from the question that you are from India. Tell your senior he/she is using a hackneyed, dull and needless phrase. This is passe now.

Comment: That sounds more like a playful jibe than a correction.

Comment: @shyam : sure :)

Comment: That's awfully prescriptive. *Level* is merely an intensifier, shop-worn though it may be, and does bolster the assertion a bit.

Comment: @Robusto, I agree. See this interesting explanation of the origins of *level best* from a January 1899 periodical. http://books.google.com/books?id=sW7UAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA304&dq=%22level+best%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fxOQT5bPC6rv6AH0s8S2BA&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22level%20best%22&f=false

Comment: @Robusto: Not my personal opinion this. Adding an extra qualifier does make it sound stilted. That it is unnecessary is rather commonly understood: http://www.english-for-students.com/My-Level-Best.html

Comment: @Shyam - your link says that saying "level best" is fine. 
> There is nothing wrong in saying level best.

Comment: @MattЭллен: Exactly, I never said it is wrong per se. It is just an unnecessary use of a word. I know colleagues in the IT industry who had been told to cut down 'level' as it does not sound formal. I do not know about formality, but personally feel "level best" is one for purple prose.

Comment: The link to the Assembly Herald by @JLG is the only response on the page that gets at the first question posed.  While some people might use the phrase "do my level best" when they mean "do my best," the former may carry a connotation that the latter does not.  They are not the same; level is not an "intensifier."  I recently heard the former phrase used as a partial rebuke of one professor by another, where the connotation was that she worked hard enough to get the job done, but made no attempt to smooth over the rough edges of the academic calendar for her students.

Answer (score 10):

Curiously, the statements

> I will do my best.

and

> I will do my level best.

are, on the face of it, assurances that the speaker intends to try hard and really hard, respectively. But they also can be used to cast doubt on the assertion. If someone gives you a task you feel is impossible to perform, responding with "I will do my best" actually can mean you believe you will fail even though you are going to try as hard as you are able. Adding "level" or any other intensifier can be used to enhance the mood of doubt.

Ain't English grand?